# Remove Elements with a prefix

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, removeall

I'm trying to remove all the elements of an arrayList that have the same prefix, this is my code

```
public void removeWordsWithPrefix(String prefix)  { 

    for(Concept def:list){
      if(def.getName().toLowerCase().substring(0,prefix.length()).equals(prefix.toLowerCase() )) 
        {
            list.remove(def);
        }

    }       
}
```

The problem is that only removes the first word with that prefix and not the others.

Answer (score 0):

When removing entries from a list, you should iterate backwards; for example:

```
for(int i = list.size()-1; i >= 0; i--) {
  // you're free to remove an item from index i here
}
```

If you want to add some more boilerplate, you can also use the `Iterator` returned by `list.iterator()`.

Answer (score 0):

firstly startsWith(prefix) will do the job instead of substring and equals.

secondly, you cannot remove from the list you iterating over unless you using iterator (depending on the list implementatin you may get exception or unexpected behaviour).

So use explicit iterator instead and its remove method,
or iterrate using indexes.